# C# automatically sign into a specific site that's not yours

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, authentication

What are some ways to go about signing into a website that you did not build yourself using C# code. All I can really tell about the site is that it is ASP.net. Using Google Chrome, I can poke around the structure of the site. Under the Resources tab in Chrome, in the Cookies section, I see things such as: ASP.Net_SessionId, SiteAuthCookie, user_IsCultureSet, user_RptParams. Wasn't sure if those could be utilized. I know with certain URL's, you can append the username & password to the end of the string, but I figured that is not always plausible with every site. I've never attempted anything like this, so I had no idea where to start. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether the site uses forms based authentication (manages its own username/password database) or an external authentication server.

The easiest way to find out what goes on when a user logs in is to start [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or the debugging tools in your browser and look at the requests being made.

Comment: I downloaded Fiddler, I have no idea if I am looking in the right area, however here are the Request Handlers in order that I get after clicking the login button: CONNECT site.com:443 HTTP/1.1, CONNECT site:443 HTTP/1.1, POST /Login.aspx HTTP/1.1, GET /default.aspx HTTP/1.1, GET /Page1.aspx HTTP/1.1, GET /Functions.asmx/js HTTP/1.1, POST /Page1.aspx HTTP/1.1

Comment: Inspect the POST /Login.aspx request. I suspect you'll see credentials in the POST body and the response is setting some cookies. If you can build the POST request from your command line tool and capture the cookies from the response, you should be able to authenticate from an external app.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Do you happen to have a link to a guide/tutorial for building such a POST request in command line. When I googled it, I got a lot of 'curl' responses. Is that the way to go?

Comment: Curl is a command line tool to issue HTTP requests. But if you're coding in C# take a look at the HttpClient class.